# python3 woes with passing string to stdin of subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, pipe

How do I make this unix command ... work in python3?

## unix command

```
echo 'alter table in db' | zenity --text-info --width 600 --height 300 --title 'has this sql been done?'
```

The command above pops up a box with the text and I can then capture the user's response.

In python3 I thought I could just write this to the stdin of a subprocess but I keep getting cryptic errors that I am unable to get round

## below is the python program to do this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

cmd = ['zenity', '--text-info', '--width', 600, '--height', 300, '--title', 'has this sql been done?']

pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

data='alter table in db'

resp = pipe.communicate(input=data)[0]
```

this python script however fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1275, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int
```

***any ideas will be much appreciated***

Comment: Your first cmd list contains ints; 600 and 300. I think this is your first problem.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
cmd = ['zenity', '--text-info', '--width', 600, '--height', 300, '--title', 'has this sql been done?']
```

should be this:

```
cmd = ['zenity', '--text-info', '--width', '600', '--height', '300', '--title', 'has this sql been done?']
```

even 300 and 600 are meant to be numbers, you still present them as strings in the command line.

Comment: thanks Adrian, I had two issues. the command needed to have quotes around the INTs like you rightly said, but also I cannot just send text to the input of the pipe, it had to be converted to a bytearray  (e..g bytearray('plain text', 'utf-8')  as opposed to just 'plain text' which works in a unix shell)

Comment: I believe you're using Python 3. In Python, you have string, which is unicode (without any specific encoding). However, when you send the string to elsewhere (e.g. save to a file), you MUST give a encoding to it. Therefore, you're correct that it have to be converted into a byte string first (but for me, I will just do `"string".encode("utf-8")`). If you prefer to make this implicit: in `Popen()`, pass in `universal_newlines=True`.

Answer (score 0):

## !/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

cmd = ['zenity', '--text-info', '--width', '600', '--height', '300', '--title', 'has this sql been done?']

pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

data='alter table in db'

resp = pipe.communicate(input=bytearray(data, 'utf-8'))[0]